JWT Token returns NULL .NET API Login
I'm trying to generate JWT Token to an API response for login, but it returns null.
It is a standard JWT method to have token generated. Here is my code and logging output:
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _db;
    private string secretkey;

    public UserRepository(AppDbContext db, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _db = db;
        secretkey = config.GetValue<string>("ApiSettings", "Secret");
    }

public async Task<LoginResponseDTO> Login(LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDto)
    {
        var user = await _db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == loginRequestDto.UserName.ToLower());

        if (user == null)
        {
            return new LoginResponseDTO()
            {
                Token = "",
                User = null
            };
        }

        // if user was found generate then the JWT Token

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretkey);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        LoginResponseDTO loginResponse = new()
        {
            Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
            User = user,
        };
        return loginResponse;
    }
}


I tried changing expires and claims, but nothing seems to work.

The yellow line has not yet been completed on your image. You have to click f11 one more time

I had a test in my side and reproduced your issue, https://i.sstatic.net/cbrbaogY.png   Just like what you can see in the screenshot,your app failed to get the secretKey from appsettings.json so that it used the default value Secret which is not suitable for playing the role of a secret key which is too short. I agree with what Big Fudge post below to make sure your app could get the key.

The issue is likely due to a misconfiguration in how the secret key is being retrieved from configuration.
The GetValue() method's parameters are incorrect.
Try changing this line ->
secretkey = config.GetValue("ApiSettings", "Secret");
// In the constructor, change this line:
secretkey = config.GetValue<string>("ApiSettings", "Secret");

// To this:
secretkey = config.GetValue<string>("ApiSettings:Secret");
// OR
secretkey = config["ApiSettings:Secret"];

Make sure your appsettings.json has the secret key configured like this:
{
  "ApiSettings": {
    "Secret": "YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE"
  }
}

